# How to check memory leakage of javascript running as devtool

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools

There are lots of information regarding how to check javascript memory running inside certain page, but I need to check the memory usage of my javascript inputted via console.

I am developing some scripts to work as robot like game assistant, so I put my script under the thread(frame) and triggered by setInterval calls every second. Sample code like following:

```
var msgList = [];
var msgGenerator = function () {
    return "Welcome";
}

var msgInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var msg = msgGenerator();
        if (!msgList.includes(msg))
            msgList.push(msg);
    }, 1 * 1000);
```

Actually the message is very small and in total it will be less than 50. But the memory of such devtool(viewed from task manager of chrome) is increasing.
Even after I execute the following call:
clearInterval(msgInterval);
The memeory of devtool is still increasing.
Can anyone guide me how to get memory snapshot of devtool(javascript running on console)? Or is there any other way to analyze the memory leakage of homemade javascript running on console?

Comment: I found another way to run as chrome snippets or firefox scratchpad. However, still there is no way to check the memory usage of either snippets or scratchpad. If anyone find a solution, please let me know, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tried many ways to get the detail memory usage of devtool but failed. It seems there is no such tool/facility. Anyway, if someone found such tool later, please post in this thread.

However, I find the way to avoid memory usage increase of my script running on console: change the setInterval to setTimeout, and achieve the same effect.

The updated codes as following will not have any memory usage increasing any more.

```
var msgList = [];
var msgGenerator = function () {
    return "Welcome";
}

var msgInterval = 0;
var msgLoop = function () {
    var msg = msgGenerator();
    if (!msgList.includes(msg))
        msgList.push(msg);
    msgInterval = setTimeout(msgLoop, 1 * 1000);
};
```

Hope above message can help someone is struggling to solve the "memory leakage" of console scripts or snippets.